# How to install LINE (messaging app) on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, wine

I would like to install [LINE](http://line.me/) chat platform on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system. Please, could anyone provide me the steps to successfully install this software?. I've been trying to install this software using wine but I couldn't succeed it.

Comment: Line is a Chat platform similar to Whatsapp and it's available for Android and Windows but does not support Linux at the first sight. However I've been doing some research and I found that people installed this software using wine.

Comment: @VictorDoors It looks like you've answered the question: get wine, install line in wine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, here is a tutorial about how to install Line on Ubuntu 12.04

### PREVIOUS STEPS

PREVIOUS STEP 1: install p7zip-full from the Ubuntu Software Repository

PREVIOUS STEP 2: Install vcrun2008 with winetricks. This second step is quite tough, here are the instructions:

- Getting Winetricks (Note: Winetricks is also available from Ubuntu repository):

  wget http://winetricks.org/winetricks

  chmod +x winetricks
- Open Winetricks:

  ./winetricks
- An Interface is prompted select the default profile
- Select "Install a Windows DLL or component"; click OK
- Select vcrun2008S; click OK
- Follow the installation instructions.

---

### LINE INSTALLATION

STEP 1 : Open a Terminal and create a new temporal directory and move to it:

```
mkdir line_tmp
cd line_tmp
```

STEP 2 : Get the last Line software version from the official website:

```
wget http://dl.desktop.line.naver.jp/naver/LINE/win/LineInst.exe
7z x -y LineInst.exe
```

STEP 3: Procced with the installation as state on [this website](http://solutions4linux.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/line-messenger-under-ubuntu-1204-with.html):

```
 inode1=$(ls -ilab | awk 'FNR == 4 {print $1}')
 inode2=$(ls -ilab | awk 'FNR == 6 {print $1}')
 find . -inum $inode1 -exec mv {} LINE \;
 find . -inum $inode2 -exec mv {} resources \;
 mv ./resources/res ./LINE
 mv ./LINE ../
 cd ..
 rm -R line_tmp
```

STEP 4:

- Go to your home folder
- there is a folder named Line and inside the Line.exe file
- Open this file with wine.

Comment: Winetricks is available in the repository. You can use apt-get to install it.

Comment: @muru Thank you! I edited my answer with the information you provided

Answer (score 21):

The easiest solution is to install Chromium (or Google Chrome), and run LINE on top of it.

1. Install Chromium for the Ubuntu repository
2. Run Chromium
3. Within Chromium, go to http://line.me click on "Download" then click on "Chrome"
4. Click "Install"
5. The LINE app should start, asking you to enter your password

LINE running on my Ubuntu via Chromium:

[image: LINE Ubuntu]

Please note that the Chrome LINE app is quite basic:

- As @Kasun points out, it does not support video calls. Actually it does not seem to support normal calls either.
- As @jeffmcneill points out, there are no threaded discussions, no calls, no multiple windows, and there are issues with animated stickers.

Comment: this works but I am unable to take video calls? how to fix it

Comment: There are many weaknesses to the chrome app version, including threaded discussions, issues with animated stickers, call support, no multiple windows, etc., etc.

Comment: @jeffmcneill: Thanks, I included your feedback into the answer! Would you mind detailing the "etc etc" part? Even if it is a very long list, it is interesting information to have. Cheers!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul because it is in a separate boxed chrome window, it doesn't maintain state (for example, allowing password to be saved using chrome password). The icon is very ugly/distored on the task bar (it upsizes the favicon). There are other oddities and annoyances. See the reviews on the chrome store app for more: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/line/ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc?hl=en

Comment: How can I open LINE extension in new tab instead of new window?

Comment: @JimChen: I think that should be a new question, here or at superuser.com :-) Cheers!