# LINE app Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10

I want to install LINE app on this laptop. Acer 315 41g  with Ubuntu linux version 18.10 installed.   I searched for info but found little and years old.

Line APP https://line.me/en-US/download  "Line is a Chat platform similar to Whatsapp and it's available for Android and Windows but does not support Linux at the first sight."

I am very new to Linux, and also to Ask Ubuntu, apologies for errors due my current lack of understanding of both.

Comment: Please confirm your version of Ubuntu, you've tagged 18.04 LTS (2018-April) release of Ubuntu (18.04) but then mention a January release (there is no 18.01 or 18.1) but could mean 18.10 (2018-October).  *Ubuntu releases are yy.mm in format*.    The following may still be helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/517932/how-to-install-line-messaging-app-on-ubuntu

Comment: First:  I am new to Linux.  With that said, I downloaded and created a bootable usb for a linux 18.1  see;  https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/10/ubuntu-18-10-released-review

Comment: You've linked to an article that mentions the 2018-October (18.10) release of Ubuntu.   The .10 is not a decimal but the number 10 or ten representing October or the month of release.   The significance of the *yy.mm* is that 18.10 is not a LTS or long-term-support release of Ubuntu and thus has only 9 months of supported life.  18.10 + 9 = 19.07 EOL allowing easy calculation of end-of-support.  LTS releases have 5 years of support, so 18.04 LTS + 5y = 2023.04 EOL

Comment: according to this I have Ubuntu 18.1  'https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/10/ubuntu-18-10-released-review'  I am a newbie to Linux, I downloaded what was labled as  Ubunto 18.1 .iso, created an install usb drive and....    The tag is 18.04 because it was already there and I apparently do not qualify to create new tag.  (18.1)

Comment: Sorry for confusing this conversation, I didn't see the first one actually post, so I redid my post, essentially saying the same thing, 2nd post is NOT meant as argument

Comment: thanks for the clarification on LTS,  With enough time and help I will get there!  ;)

Comment: Please [edit] your question: 1) Correct information - It's .10, not .1, again, not a decimal. **18.10** means the Ubuntu release of year 2018 and month October. 2) Then please answer the question in comments about *what is LINE app?*. To that effect please describe what it is and how have you tried to install it and post any error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems, the best solution for now would be to install the google chrome app.

First [install google chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome) and then, in chrome follow this link:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/line/ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Comment: Thank you and yes, that is exactly what I did, so simple once you learn it can be done!!  ;)   And now, may I ask, if you know, what do I do with this posting now that it has been effectively resolved?

Comment: @TerryP. If this answer solved your problem please click the gray tickmark on the left side next to it. This way, your question will be marked as solved, helping future readers, and we both get some reputation.

Comment: maybe this is the only proper solution to have LINE on ubuntu20.04

Answer (score 2):

Apparently in the case of Line, there's an important distinction between a Chrome "APP" and a Chrome "EXTENSION".

(1) The Chrome "EXTENSION" that Bruni pointed out above does work. It was updated to 2019 July 25 as of this writing:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/line/ophjlpahpchlmihnnnihgmmeilfjmjjc

(2) In contrast, this Chrome "App" for Line, dated 2018 March 7, doesn't work on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I had used Ubuntu 14.xx and had the same issue.

Yet this "App" appears near the top of Google search results. This may be confusing users trying to install Line on desktop. Thus it is useful to point out specifically that it does not work.

This is the "APP" that should be avoided if you come across it: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/line/menkifleemblimdogmoihpfopnplikde

Comment: Likes like the "EXTENSION" mentioned above is no longer available (getting a 404).